OperadorJavaScript
El ejercicio pide:

Escribí un programa que imprima en la consola cual es el número más grande.

y no me funciona.


function CualEsMayor(numero1, numero2, numero3) {
  if (numero1 > numero2 && numero1 > numero3) {
    mayor = numero1;
  } else if (numero2 > numero1 && numero2 > numero3) {
    mayor = numero2;
  } else {
    mayor = numero3;
  }
  console.log("El mayor desde la funcion es " + mayor);
}

CualEsMayor(1, 6, 123);
CualEsMayor(123, 1, 6);
CualEsMayor(6, 123, 1);




Hola Rocio, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprendas como funciona la plataforma y de paso obtengas tu primer medalla. Será que solo te falta definir la variable mayor? Por ejemplo let mayor;

El código esta correcto únicamente tienes que llamar o ejecutar la función, para ello agrega esta línea al final CualEsMayor(21,10,3).
function CualEsMayor(numero1, numero2, numero3) {
    if (numero1 > numero2 && numero1 > numero3) {
      mayor = numero1;
    } else if (numero2 > numero1 && numero2 > numero3) {
      mayor = numero2;
    } else {
      mayor = numero3;
    }
    console.log("El mayor desde la funcion es " + mayor);
  }

CualEsMayor(21,10,3) //Llamar o ejecutar la función

Resultado
node test.js

El mayor desde la funcion es 21

